# Using vite to import CSS from a video.js npm dependency into JS

Tags: video.js, vite

I am attempting to move from webpack to vite (3.1.8).  (in the context of a Rails app, actually webpacker)

I use [video.js](https://videojs.com/).  With webpack, in a `.js` file, I am able to both import video.js *javascript*, *and* import the CSS packaged with video.js from the javascript file, like so:

```js
import videojs from 'video.js';
require('!style-loader!css-loader!video.js/dist/video-js.css')
```

The `require` like that isn't supported in vite. Normally in vite you can import CSS no problem, and it'll even be automatically spit out into a `<style> tag. As simple as, say,` import './some.css'`

But when the CSS is from an npm dependency like video.js... how do I import it?

I tried simple `import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';`, as well as `import '@video.js/dist/video-js.css';`, neither worked. In dev, both just say "Rollup failed to resolve import" upon asking vite to `vite build --development`.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Landed here wondering the same thing...  Please self-answer if you've found a way to do it.

Comment: OK, I don't want to answer, because I don't understand what I did, but I look at my source now, and I have simply `import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';` in a `.js` file... and it's working fine. Maybe try removing all vite cache files and restarting vite dev server? I'm not sure why I was having a problem or how I fixed it! At least I can confirm for you that vite is supposed to do this... and for me now is. My app is open source. https://github.com/sciencehistory/scihist_digicoll/blob/85811fd0d415744d7afafc01af2376c8b59a0267/app/frontend/javascript/video_player.js